# Cocos2d - Mac: Check for keyboard events?

Tags: objective-c, events, macos, keyboard, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d, which is a framework for creating iPhone games.
Recently they released Mac support, and I am making a simple game for Mac.

However, I am clueless about how to check when X key is pressed on the Mac's keyboard.

Objective-C

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do:

```
self.isKeyboardEnabled = YES;
```

You can then use to receive messages for key presses:

```
-(void) ccKeyUp:(NSEvent*)event;
-(void) ccKeyDown:(NSEvent*)event;
```

This should do it.

Refer here for more information:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11725

Comment: I did follow that, and I swear I did pretty much what he did, and yet my player won't move.
My player object is a class that contains all sprite animation processing etc. The class has two functions, move Right and Left. The functions are called in the Scene, when the keys are detected.

But won't do.... I am using ccKeyRight and ccKeyLeft instead, but, is there a big difference?

Comment: the ccKeyUp and ccKeyDown are for "keyboard press" and "keyboard release", not the up and down arrows on the keyboard - you need to use the two methods I placed above and then check the keycode (if you follow the information in the link you will see where they compare the "keyCode" value, each key on the keyboard has a different "keyCode" value which determines the actual key pressed.  There is no "ccKey*" list for each individual key, there is only ccKeyUp and ccKeyDown for determing if a key (any key) is pressed, and the information about that key is then passed in through the "event" object

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example :

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) 
    {
        .
        .
        .

        self.isKeyboardEnabled = YES ;

        .
        .
        .
    }
}

- (void) ccKeyDown : (NSEvent*) KeyDownEvent
{
    NSString *str_1 = [KeyDownEvent characters];
    unichar ch = [str_1 characterAtIndex:0];

    if ( ch == 97)                  // if 'a' Button Pressed Down
    {
        if ( canMoveRight == NO)
        {
            canMoveLeft = YES ;
        }

    }
    else if ( ch == 100 )           // if 'd' Button Pressed Down
    {
        if ( canMoveLeft == NO)
        {
            canMoveRight = YES ;
        }
    }
}

- (void) ccKeyUp : (NSEvent*) KeyDownEvent
{

    NSString *str_1 = [KeyDownEvent characters];
    unichar ch = [str_1 characterAtIndex:0];

    if ( ch == 97)                  // if 'a' Button Released
    {
        canMoveLeft = NO ;
    }
    else if ( ch == 100 )           // if 'd' Button Released
    {
        canMoveRight = NO ;
    }
}
```

PS : character code is based on their ASCII code .